# HD addresses and traceability question

Tags: address-generation

Say I have 1 underlying Bitcoin address, and it has receiving address A and B, and they both received 2 BTC each. If spend 3 BTC then A and B would have spent together so it's probably traceable. What about if I spend 2 BTC (or emptying address B exactly)?  Can B and A still be linked?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> **Can B and A still be linked?**

Not directly.

However it depends on context and external patterns and information.

For example if G sends 2 BTC each month to addresses A, B, C and so on,  and G sends no money elsewhere, people could infer that there is a connection between A and B. They could speculate about the nature of that connection. Some of those speculations might happen to be correct. There might be other transactions or other external information people could use to look for supporting evidence for those speculations.